# getting data from one table to another in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have two tables called registration and user.

Registration table:

```
PID(primary key,autoincrement)
email
password
name
etc
```

User:

```
UserID
Address
etc
```

If any person gets registered then data is stored in registration table.

Now if I want to insert data in user table then how can I insert data for that particular person which has just registered himself?

Ex: registration table

```
PID  email        name
1    abc@ab.com   xyz
```

I want to insert data into user table which has `PID=1`

And after login (which is done with the help of email and password) only person can insert data in USER table.

What is the query for this?

Should I add some common columns in `User` table?

Comment: How do the two tables relate to each other?  I don't see an obvious column to base a relationship on.

Comment: Its not clear what do you want to do after login? Insert into users table again? Read data from users table?

Comment: Maybe add column PID to the users table to be foreign key to the register table

Comment: I dont know much about databse..I want to add into user table and that data should relate to registration table.

Comment: ya..after login i want to insert into USER table and that details should relate to registration table
So when i fetch data for perticular person then i should get details of both the tables Registration and USER

Answer (score 0):

Add new column to Users table:

PId - it should be foreign key to the Pid column in Registration table. Read about foreign keys here:

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp

The query to insert into users table should be:

```
Insert into Users(pid,email,name) values(1,'abc@ab.com','xyz')
```

Maybe you want to check that there isnt such user with those credentials that is alread registered? So maybe try to select such user first and only insert if there isnt one, so to check, you should first add:

```
If Not exists(select 1 from Registration where pid = 1)
```

The query to fetch the data when you login should be:

```
Select * from users join registration on users.pid = registration.pid
Where registration.username = 'given user name'
```

Or instead of username, compare by any other column from any of the two tables. You can do it because you joined both tables into one table.

Read about join here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191517(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Please don't cite w3schools, they are known to subvert standards and promote bad practices (http://w3fools.com/).  A better reference would be Microsoft (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175464(v=sql.105).aspx) or even Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key)

Comment: You are right :) but I guess even they cant go wrong with explaining about foreign keys :)

Answer (score 0):

just create trigger on table registration table.so that when someone registered it will automatically insert data into user table also.

for that write insert after trigger in registration table.

check out this link for example:

http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/sqlserver/OPUH170312-After-Trigger,-Instead-of-Trigger-Example.html